# Get cookie from Golang post

Tags: ruby, go

How do I send the post in GoLang?

I have the following code in `ruby`, now I need to transfer into Golang.

```
http = Net::HTTP.new('example.com', 443)
http.use_ssl = true
http

path = '/abc/login'
data = 'data[Account][username]=myusername&data[Account][passwd]=mypassword'
resp, _ = http.post(path, data)
```

This way, I can get the cookie after login request.

But I don't know how to send a post request in Go.

I've written the following code.

```
path := "https://example.com/abc/login"
data := strings.NewReader("data[Account][username]=myusername&data[Account][passwd]=mypassword")
resp, err := http.Post(path, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", data)
```

It seems not correct, because I didn't find a way to get cookie.

Comment: Your title and question don't match at all. Are you asking about how to send a POST, or how to get a cookie?

Comment: `data[Account][username]=myusername&data[Account][passwd]=mypassword` is not `text/html` in the least.

Comment: @Flimzy, actually, I am not sure how to send the post, so I can get the cookie. I don't know why to cause this problem. It might have some error of post, it might have errors when getting the cookie.

Comment: @mkopriva, I post in google chrome, and it states the content type is `text/html`.  So what is the correct format of `data[Account][username]=myusername&data[Account][passwd]=mypassword` ?

Comment: @CodaChang, if the Content-Type header is not set manually, ruby's http.post(path, data) sets it automatically to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-post

Comment: Thanks, it seems the website take both `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `text/html` as well.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To get the cookies you should call the `Cookies()` method that's part of `http.Response`, try this:

```
for _, cookie := range resp.Cookies() {
  fmt.Println("Found a cookie named:", cookie.Name)
}
```

See the `Cookie` fields [here](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Cookie).

Answer (score 12):

//Create Client

```
client=http.client{}
```

//Create Varible

```
var cookie []*http.Cookie
```

//  Create Request

```
req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
resp, err := client.Do(req) //send request
if err != nil {
return 
}
cookie = resp.Cookies() //save cookies
```

//  Create New Request

```
req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", url, nil)   
for i := range cookie {
    req.AddCookie(cookie[i])
}
resp, err := client.Do(req) //send request
if err != nil {
      return 
              }
```